# Derived class template

Tags: c++, templates, derived-class

I have some question on derived class templates. I have base and derived class templates like this:

```
// This is base class
class CParameter {
public:
   CParameter(std::string name) : name(name) {}
// virtual ~CParameter() {} // deleted for good design:)

public:
   std::string name;
};
```

...

```
// This is derived class
template <typename T>
class CTemplateParameter : public CParameter {
public:
   CTemplateParameter(std::string name) : CParameter(name) {}
public:
   T parameter;
};
```

**and I declare some type parameters the push them to base class vector**

```
//Base class parameters
std::vector<CParameter*> parameters; // !
CTemplateParameter<CMatrix4<float>> mat4;
CTemplateParameter<CVector3<float>> vec3;
CTemplateParameter<float> flt;

parameters.push_back(mat4);
parameters.push_back(vec3);
parameters.push_back(flt);
```

**I have template SetParameter function:**

```
// This method moved to CParameter base class
template <typename T>
bool SetParameter(const CTemplateParameter<T>& param) {
// switch(typeof(T)) {
// set parameter
if (std::is_same<T, int>::value)
   // gLUniform1i(...)
else if (std::is_same<T, CMatrix4<float>>::value)
   // glUniformMatrix4fv(..)
...
```

}

So my questions:

1) How to set all parameter individual?

```
// Notice this function is not template
void SetAll() {
   for each parameter
      SetParameter(parameter[i])
}
```

2) Without enum, can I get type of parameter and create a type in run time? Like:

```
Pseudo code:
    //get type of parameter[i]
    //create a parameter from
    T type = GetTypeofParameter(parameter[i]);
    CTemplateParameter<type> newType;
```

3) Can i get a derived class type like this or how to cast?

```
CTemplateParameter<void*>* p = dynamic_cast<CTemplateParameter<void*>>(parameters[i]);
```

Thanks so much.

Comment: 1) You seem to have painted yourself into the corner in which mixing `virtual` and `template` is required.  Usually those are alternate approaches and you should select one or the other.  Mixing that way is often a design error.  But you don't seem to have left yourself much choice:  `SetParameter` should be `virtual` (implying it is a member of CParameter, rather than taking one).  For your other questions, I don't understand what you want.

Comment: Exactly:). So I understand that your answer I have to choose one of them.. "template" or "derived class" method, indeed?. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: No, you don't "have to choose" and I never said `template` vs. derived, but `template` vs. `virtual`.  There is no bad design implied by a template being derived from a non template.  It is usually bad design for a `template` parameter and a `virtual` function to both dispatch on the same underlying choice.  But even then, no rule says you can't.

Comment: Using a bunch of `std::is_same` tests is a terrible way to dispatch inside `setParameter`.  Many versions of an overloaded function would make a lot more sense.  Also it is bizarre that you showed `setParameter` as global, rather than as a member of the target object.  (You gave us no clue what the target object might be).  One possible design is to make `setParameter` a CRTP virtual member of the source objects which in turn call another `setParameter`, which is a simple overloaded function of the target object.

Comment: Thank you JSP! For virtual destructor; Its "copy-paste" base class code.. I edited my question and delete them.Yes SetParameter is a member template function of another class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My comments seem to have pushed ADesignersEncyclopedia away from a template/virtual mix but not toward a practical alternative.  The original question doesn't give enough info to decide whether there is a practical alternative.  Lacking such a practical alternative, do the virtual/template mix correctly (with CRTP) rather than reject it entirely:

In your target class, you want `setParameter` in two forms, neither of which is a template.  The first form dispatches to the `setParameter` inside the parameter class, which dispatches back to the second form in the target class:

```
bool SetParameter(const CParameter& param) {
   return param.SetParameter( *this );
}
```

The second form is overloaded on the value type:

```
bool SetParameter(int value) {
   // whatever
}
bool SetParameter(CMatrix4<float> const& value) {
   // whatever
}
...
```

In your parameter base class, you want SetParameter pure virtual

```
class CParameter
{
    ...
    virtual bool SetParameter( TargetType& ) const = 0;
    ...
};
```

Then you need a CRTP base class, which should be derived from your simple base class:

```
template<class ActualType>
class CRTPParameter : public CParameter
{
  CRTPParameter(std::string name) : CParameter(name) {}
  ActualType* This() {return static_cast<ActualType*>(this); }
  ActualType const* This() const {return static_cast<ActualType const*>(this); }
  // various things including
  ActualType* clone() const { return new ActualType( *This() ); }
  bool SetParameter( TargetType& target ) const
  { return target.SetParameter( This()->parameter ); }
};
```

Then your template class derives from your CRTP class

```
template <typename T>
class CTemplateParameter : public CRTPParameter<CTemplateParameter<T> > {
public:
   typedef CRTPParameter<CTemplateParameter<T> super;
   CTemplateParameter(std::string name) : super(name) {}
```

If everything else is simple enough, then the whole CRTP scheme might be overkill and you could just move clone and SetParameter from CRTPParameter to CTemplateParameter and go back to not having CRTPParameter.

But in my experience with such structures, things soon get messy in CTemplateParameter in ways that a best dealt with by the extra layer.

Comment: Thank you JSF. I moved SetParameter implementition to CParameter class then its solved my problem. My target is pass individual parameters to opengl program. I used if else statement which pass parameter to glUniformxx() function. Opengl and oo design is a little hard. I want to bind each parameter set automaticaly rather then manually  bind. I edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

1/
You should define `setParameter` in `Cparameter` as an abstract method, and implement it in your template class.

2/
I suggest to use a clone(or a factory) method, defined as I suggested in 1/. In this method you can copy(or create) your object then define it.

3/
No. You can't cast `CtemplateParameter<float>` to `CtemplateParameter<void*>`

Comment: Thank you Brahim. Do I need to use CMatrix4Parameter, CVectorParameter, CFloatParameter derived class instead of template?

Comment: You can call the copy constructor of the type `T` and avoiding specializing the template

Comment: If clone is the correct answer to (2) then this is the common situation in which CRTP is the best way to implement the clone function (do a search for CRTP).  But anyway, you do **not** want use all those differently named classes derived from Cparameter.  The mixture of `virtual` and `template` you seem to be forcing on yourself might or might not be a good design, but it is clearly better than all those named classes.  If you need that virtual/template mix in setParameter, then CRTP is probably best for that as well.

Answer (score 0):

> 1) How to set all parameter individual?

You can't iterate and set the value for all of them, unless you know the type. And put a huge amount of dynamic_cast would not be the solution either as it is not scalable.
One solution would be to keep a map of `std::function`. These function would not take any parameter and return nothing. They will set the parameter with the right values. Pushing into the vector would be like this:

```
std::map<CParameter*, std::function<void()>> mySets;

// ...

mySets.emplace(&parameter, [ObjectThatGiveMeNext, &parameter]() {
    parameter.setParameter(ObjectThatGiveMeNext.get());
});
```

Even if you contain the parameter, it is not your main container for parameters. It is only to keep track of which parameter is associated to which function.

The ideal would be to create this function when you create the parameter, because you know the type of the parameter there.

Another solution would be to create a virtual function `updateValue` that would call `setParameter` with `this`.

> 2) Without enum, can I get type of parameter and create a type in run time?

That is not really possible it's a context where you don't know the type, so you must either know the type (a switch case) or rely on polymorphic behaviour. I think the best here is to rely on polymorphic behaviour.

I would add a virtual function clone for that. Maybe not the famous straight `clone` function, but a clone function that return both the parameter and the function to set it's value. Something a bit like that:

```
std::tuple<std::unique_ptr<CParameter>, std::function<void()>> clone();
```

Consider a typedef or using in this case as the type is loooooong.

> 3) Can i get a derived class type like this or how to cast?

No you can't. You would need to convert the instance of your class to another, not related type. I would not do that. Instead, keep your code that deal with your specific derived class where you explicitely know the type and keep the generic code generic (eg: not trying to know the type). This is the best advice I can tell you right now.

Comment: Brilliant! :) Thank you for your detailed answer and code samples.